# SAML2.0 Assertions vs. SAML2.0 Messages

Tags: saml-2.0

I need a clarification about the terminology used in SAML2.0. I want to know if by "assertions" we mean a particular subcategory of SAML2.0 messages
or if we mean ALL SAML2.0 messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SAML Assertion is an XML document that represents a set of claims (i.e. name/value pairs) about a user asserted by an Identity Provider. A SAML Assertion is not a SAML message itself, but it is contained in a SAML Response message. Apart from that there are other SAML messages such as SAML Requests, Logout Requests and Logout Responses that don't contain Assertions.

Comment: Thanks, that's the explanation I was looking for